# Spring Security Configuration Kotlin DSL

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

So, I have this java code inside my configurer adapter:

```
http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, Constants.CREATE_USER_URL).permitAll()
    .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html**", "/webjars/**", "favicon.ico").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager())).addFilter(new BasicJwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

And I try using the new Kotlin DSL:

```
http {
  cors { disable() }
  csrf { disable() }
  authorizeRequests {
    authorize(AntPathRequestMatcher(createUserUrl, HttpMethod.POST.name), permitAll)
    authorize(AntPathRequestMatcher("favicon.ico", HttpMethod.GET.name), permitAll)
    authorize(AntPathRequestMatcher("/v2/api-docs", HttpMethod.GET.name), permitAll)
    authorize(AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-resources/**", HttpMethod.GET.name), permitAll)
    authorize(AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**", HttpMethod.GET.name), permitAll)
    authorize(AntPathRequestMatcher("/webjars/**", HttpMethod.GET.name), permitAll)
    authorize(anyRequest, authenticated)
  }
  addFilterAt(JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), AuthenticationFilter::class.java)
  addFilterAt(BasicJwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
  sessionManagement { SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS }
}
```

Is this kotlin dsl have the same functionality with the java code? Is there no `addFilter` for kotlin dsl?

Could I reduce redundant `authorize` (on the Java Code, it used antMatchers which accept multiple patterns) that have similar code (`permitAll HTTP GET`)??

Comment: Other option is is to use `authorize(EndpointRequest.to("/a", "/b", "/c"), permitAll)`, although I don't think you can specify which exact HTTP method to allow, so it permits every method.

Comment: @kdev I tried using for loops inside the kotlin dsl. Is there anything wrong with this approach?? It compiled, and run ok, but have not tested it properly.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with that. You can create extension method on dsl, and call it the same `authorize` which accepts: HTTP method and vararg string endpoints as parameters and inside the method iterates and registers them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Kotlin configuration is not equivalent to the Java configuration that you shared.

First, the CORS configuration

```java
http
    .cors()
    .and()
    // ...
```

Below is the equivalent Kotlin configuration, since you are enabling CORS rather than disabling it.

```kotlin
http {
    cors { }
}
```

Second, the session management configuration

```java
http
    // ...
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

Below is the equivalent Kotlin configuration, where you want to assign the SessionCreationPolicy.

```
http {
    sessionManagement {
        sessionCreationPolicy = SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS
    }
}
```

Regarding the `addFilter` method, in the Javadoc it states

> Adds Filter that must be an instance of or extend one of the Filters provided within the Security framework.

If your custom filter `BasicJwtAuthenticationFilter` is an instance of `BasicAuthenticationFilter`, then the Kotlin configuration is correct.

Adding all of this together, you get the following Kotlin configuration

```kotlin
http {
    cors { }
    csrf { disable() }
    authorizeRequests {
        authorize(AntPathRequestMatcher(createUserUrl, HttpMethod.POST.name), permitAll)
        authorize(AntPathRequestMatcher("favicon.ico", HttpMethod.GET.name), permitAll)
        authorize(AntPathRequestMatcher("/v2/api-docs", HttpMethod.GET.name), permitAll)
        authorize(AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-resources/**", HttpMethod.GET.name), permitAll)
        authorize(AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**", HttpMethod.GET.name), permitAll)
        authorize(AntPathRequestMatcher("/webjars/**", HttpMethod.GET.name), permitAll)
        authorize(anyRequest, authenticated)
    }
    addFilterAt(JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), AuthenticationFilter::class.java)
    addFilterAt(BasicJwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
    sessionManagement {
        sessionCreationPolicy = SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS
    }
}
```